# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (s >= 0) in void cv::setSize(cv::Mat&, int, int const*, const size_t*, bool)

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to opencv library. I am trying to stitch the images using openCv, while running it's giving exception "Assertion failed (s >= 0) in void cv::setSize". Please help me. Here is my code..

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_imagejoiner_MyJoiner_stitchImages(
        JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis, jobjectArray jfilePaths,
        jstring jfinalImagePath) {

vector<Mat> imgs;
imgs.clear();

Mat imgMat;

bool try_use_gpu = false;

const int imageCount = env->GetArrayLength(jfilePaths);

for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {

    jstring filePath = (jstring) env->GetObjectArrayElement(jfilePaths, i);

    const char *rawString = env->GetStringUTFChars(filePath, 0);

    LOGV("RESULT = %s", rawString);

    imgMat = imread(rawString);

    if (!imgMat.empty()) {
        LOGV("Mat added.....");
        LOGV("RESULT = %d", i);
        imgs.push_back(imgMat);
    }

}

imgMat.release();

const char *finalImagePath = env->GetStringUTFChars(jfinalImagePath, 0);

LOGV("RESULT = %s", finalImagePath);

Mat pano;

Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(try_use_gpu);
Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano);

imgs.clear();

LOGV("RESULT = %s", "done mat.....");

imwrite(finalImagePath, pano);

LOGV("RESULT = %s", "done writing.....");

pano.release();
}
```

Comment: In which line of the above listing does the error occur?

Comment: "imwrite(finalImagepath, pano)" -- error occured exactly here nils.

Comment: Did you check the return code `status` from `stitcher.stitch()`?

Comment: I could not get any status code sir. exception raising while calling the sticher.sticher(). sir. Roger Rowland